# Project runs on Windows 7 but not on Linux with Virtual Box

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, linux-mint

I'm having a problem with a C++ project I made on Windows 7 using code-blocks. There it compiles perfectly and executes the program as desired however when I tried opening it with Virtual Box using Linux Mint Cinnamon 17 the program compiles but throws a segmentation fault error at runtime (more specifically "segmentation fault process returned 139 0x8b". I gave the Virtual Machine 2 GB of RAM. and here is the code which causes the program to stop.

```
string Tabla::linea(contenedor& lista, int lis_s)
{     //contenedor is: vector < vector <string> >
    ostringstream os;
    os<<"|";
    for(int i=0; i< lista.size();i++)
    {   int espacios =maximos[i]-lista[i][lis_s].size();
        if(lista[i][0]=="<")
        {
           os<<" "<<lista[i][lis_s]<<string(espacios,' ')<<" ";
        }
        if(lista[i][0]==">")
        {
            os<<" "<<string(espacios,' ')<<lista[i][lis_s]<<" ";
        }
        if(lista[i][0]=="=")
        {
            os<<" "<<string( espacios / 2,' ')<<
                lista[i][lis_s]<<string(espacios / 2,' ')<<" ";

            if(espacios%2==1)
                os << " ";
        }


        os<<"|";
    }

    return os.str();
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Debuggers are helpful in situations like this.

Comment: Make sure that `lista[i].size() > 0` before accessing `lista[i][...]`.

Comment: Hi @Havenard it is a vector which contains ints indicating the maximum size of strings found on each sub vector of lista since it is a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as "undefined behaviour", its when your code does something its not supposed to do, like read or write an out of bound element from a vector, write to a buffer that cannot hold as much data as you are trying to write to it etc.

It may result on a variety of unpredictable consequences like segmentation fault, stack overflow, memory overwrite, and it may even complete its task without aparent incidents.

This particular piece of code can be invoking undefined behaviour in numerous situations:

If `maximos.size()` is smaller than `lista.size()` its undefined behaviour when calculating `espacios`.

If `lista[i].size()` is smaller than `lis_s+1` it will invoke undefined behaviour on every place of your code that refers to `lis_s`.

If `lista[i].size()` is smaller than `1` its undefined behavior on line `if(lista[i][0]=="=")`.

Basically you have to make sure every element from those vectors you want to access exist before acessing them. You can either do that by checking all the sizes or make sure you set up everything right when populating those vectors with information.